# How to remove one string and one digit in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to remove one character and one digit.

so it is my example

```
text = "a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB 1 2 34 2313??!!"

def remove(x) :
    m = re.sub( r"([\W\s\n\r\tㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ]+[0-9]{1})" ," " , x).strip() 
    return m

I try it


remove("a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB 1 2 34 2313??!!")

but my result is 
'a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB   4 313??!!'
```

I want like this. 
**ba aB 가나다라 AB 34 2313**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete single character and all `?`, `!` you could use this ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GwMw20/2)):

```
text = "a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB 1 2 34 2313??!!"

import re

print(re.sub(r'(?:\b\w\b|[?!]+)\s*', '', text))
```

Prints:

```
ba aB 가나라다라 AB 34 2313
```

EDIT:

```
text = "가 a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB 1 2 34 2313??!!"

import re

print(re.sub(r'(?:\b[^가\s]\b|[?!]+)\s*', '', text))
```

Prints:

```
가 ba aB 가나라다라 AB 34 2313
```

Comment: Can I have a question? 
if text = ""가 a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB 1 2 34 2313??!!""
The result is " ba aB 가나라다라 AB 34 2313 "
but I want to  "가 ba aB 가나라다라 AB 34 2313 "

Comment: Thanks!  a lot

That's fine, but I've fixed your code by fixing it.

m = re.sub(r'(?:\b[0-9a-zA-Zㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ]\b|[?!\W]+)\s*', ' ', x).strip()

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this expression is likely to work:

```
(\b[A-Za-z0-9]\b|[?!ㄱㅎㅏㅣ])
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eBYdkH/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

test_str = "a ba aB 가나라다라 A AB 1 2 34 2313??!!"

print(re.sub(r"^\s|\s$","",re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", re.sub(r"(\b[A-Za-z0-9]\b|[?!])", "", test_str))))
```

#### Output

```
ba aB 가나라다라 AB 34 2313
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eBYdkH/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/eBYdkH/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.